# Can not import database in Navcat for postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, import

I'm using Navcat client for connect my local PostgreSQL database. I created a connection. But I could not import my database on it. It showed a error message. Please take a look:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me for solving this problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, I found **scratch** word. May be its a schema name. Have you create schema in your connection? if its not, then please create schema as your requirement then import your database sql file.

Comment: No, I don't create schema in my connection. I will try this out.